# How to properly punctuate the use of multiple names at the start of a sentence of dialogue

Tags: punctuation

I am proofreading someone's work of fiction, and I'm trying to determine the best way to punctuate a sentence like the following. I typically follow the Chicago Style Guide, but I couldn't find this specific situation addressed.

> The general faced the two men.
>
> "Mr. Smith, Mr. Jones, what are you men doing here?"

When addressing multiple people at the start of a sentence, are the commas I used correct? I briefly considered ellipses, but that doesn't seem correct grammatically.

Comment: Why add _men_ in the first place when it's redundant? How about _Messrs. Smith and Jones, what are you/ the two of you  doing here?_

Comment: Honestly, the "men" was just an example. The author feels very strongly about starting the sentence in a way the general would speak. This is a real-life example of dialogue, such as when a person addresses people they are speaking to, then asks a question of them.

The crux of the question is how to punctuate multiple names at the start of a sentence, regardless of what dialogue comes after.
I know that if this were a sentence that wasn't dialogue, the "and" you added would be appropriate. But this is not how someone would speak when addressing people.

Comment: Why do you think that anybody could argue that the punctuation is **not** correct? The sentence seems to be obviously OK (taking into account that it is intended to embody a particular style of speaking), in the absence of some specific reason to think that it isn't.

Comment: The example seems perfectly fine. I would not use *Messrs* unless there is some sort of association between the two men (apart from both being addressed), because of its typical use in the title of a business. I have never heard anyone using *Messrs* when addressing people.

Comment: Are Smith and Jones military personnel subordinate to 'the general'? If so, he probably would not call them 'Mr'.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I was working under the assumption that the commas were correct, but they just looked a little strange to me, so I wanted to get affirmation.

Comment: As to whether or not to use "Mr.", I was just simplifying the actual dialog to remove extraneous info. It was really the commas I wanted affirmation on. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version is correct. It's the same as if you said, "Dave, Brian, what are you men doing here?" The titles ("Mr.") don't change this. Especially since your priority is verisimilitude in dialogue, given that you're editing fiction, it makes sense to use this simple, intuitive structure. "Messrs. Smith and Jones, what are you/the two of you doing here?" is also grammatically correct, but it's not realistic dialogue.

Comment: Hello, Eira. ELU welcomes answers supported by respectable references, linked and attributed. Answers lacking these come across as (and may merely be) opinion (and have been known to be erroneous).